# Geth --unlock starts blockchain instead of password prompt

Tags: go-ethereum

What is the reason for this behavior? I expect to see a password prompt.

```
# geth_linux --help | grep unlock
  --unlock value                      Comma separated list of accounts to unlock
```

```
# geth_linux --datadir /ssd/eth --unlock 0x764b396ca3d4d0da9e846a1360fbb168cdf0accf
INFO [03-06|18:08:54.711] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
INFO [03-06|18:08:54.711] Bumping default cache on mainnet         provided=1024 updated=4096
INFO [03-06|18:08:54.713] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
Fatal: Failed to create the protocol stack: datadir already used by another process
```